# How do I set the editor command to use *only* for edit-command-line in zsh?

Tags: zsh

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in `zsh`, I can edit the current command line in by `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL`. However, I'd like to use `nano`, and to get syntax highlighting for shell syntax there, I have to pass `-Y sh`, as `nano` doesn't recognise shell syntax automatically when editing the command line (`zsh` creates `/tmp/random-name` without a `.sh` extension to pass to `nano`).

I can execute

```
EDITOR='nano -Y sh'
VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to get the desired result. However, other programs use `$EDITOR`/`$VISUAL`, too. If I set `$EDITOR`/`$VISUAL` as above, and then do (for example) `git commit`, the commit message is highlighted as shell syntax, which I want to avoid.

I also tried

```
EDITOR='nano -Y sh' fc
```

which *did* work, however that seems a little verbose to type out each time (I might put it in a function though). Also, `fc` prepopulates the command line with the *last history* command line, and to use it, I have to type out the command. That means I could not type out some long command in `zsh` and then decide to edit it in `nano` as I could with the keyboard shortcut.

So, is there a way for me to tell `zsh` the editor/flags to use *only* for editing the command line when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> that other programs ignore? I would love some environment variable that I can set in `~/.zshrc` and then forget about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The universal way to solve every computer problem¹ is to add a level of indirection.

Instead of calling `edit-command-line`, call a wrapper function.

```
nano-command-line () {
  local VISUAL='nano -Y sh'
  edit-command-line
}
zle -N nano-command-line
bindkey '^X^E' nano-command-line
```

¹  <sub>Hyperbole.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The `zle` script uses `EDITOR` or `VISUAL`. One method would be to copy that script from wherever it hides in `$fpath` into a custom functions directory, edit the script to use a different environment name, then ensure that the custom functions directory is called before the installed-with-zsh one.

```
# in .zshrc, set something like
fpath=(~/.zsh/functions $fpath)

# then in the shell, something like
mkdir -p ~/.zsh/functions
cp /usr/share/zsh/*/functions/edit-command-line ~/.zsh/functions
```

Then edit up the `edit-command-line` file and specify a different environment variable.

Comment: Good idea, thanks! I'll wait a while to see if something else comes up before accepting your answer, if that's alright.